# unexpected token { in module export node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was writing my controller like this

```
module.exports.create_payment = function(){
    console.log('create_payment')
}
```

but there's a problem with above pattern. Imagine I have 10 method in one controller then I will have to write module.exports.method1, module.exports.method2 etc..

So to solve that I wrap and return the methods like below

```
module.exports = {

    return {

        create_payment: function(req,res,next){

            console.log('create_payment')

        }
    }
}
```

But I got error of unexpected token, what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you are assigning to `module.exports` is an object literal, not a function. You can't put a return statement in it.

```
module.exports = {
    create_payment: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('create_payment')
    }
};
```

Comment: if above code is put in a file call payment.js, can I use it like this

`var payment = require('payment'); app.post('/pay',payment.create_payment);`
 ?

Comment: strange, some where I saw people use return in controllers. Do u have to use revealing module pattern in express.js? since it has built in module exports.

Comment: If you did, it wasn't in an object literal where a property name is expected.

Comment: No. You never have to use the revealing module pattern … and it is pointless to do so in a Node module.

Comment: so object literal is the most common way of doing things in node.js? wait, in es6 there's also import and export in the front end, meaning revealing module pattern is no longer useful?